# Skip Gitlab Webhook from git or merge request message

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, webhooks, continuous-deployment

I have branch, lets called "dev" branch, I attach a webhook to call codemagic build every push/merge request on this branch.

But sometimes, I push/merge request with WIP feature, so I dont want to trigger a webhook when my commit message/merge request message contains "WIP".

Is it possible to do that on gitlab? I don't see any documentation of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [skip ci] inside the commit message or pull request title